# ASUS TUF Gaming | Drivers

Tags: asus, compatibility, motherboard

## (This is my first experience with Ubuntu)

I want to install Ubuntu (last LTS version)

### And I want to ask:

Will I have problems with drivers on TUF B450-PLUS GAMING and where can I install them for Ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: Search this site for b450.  There are 128 questions that match.